Nuxt3 button click handler: Updating isLoading Before and After Emit (@click.prevent)
In my Nuxt3 application, I have a button that triggers this event when clicked @click.prevent="$emit('method', form)". I want to enhance this button's behaviour by:
Setting isLoading to true before the event - this visually indicates that an operation is in progress.
Setting isLoading back to false after the event is complete - this signifies the operation's completion.
I'm using NuxtUI's UButton :loading component to achieve this look
I previously attempted using simple async function and promises to achieve this:
<script setup>
const isLoading = ref(false);
const emit = defineEmits(['method']);

const handleClick = async () => {
  isLoading.value = true;
  try {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      emit('method', form);
    });
  } finally {
    isLoading.value = false;
  }
};
</script>

<template>
...
<UButton :loading="isLoading" @click.prevent="handleClick">
   {{ btn.text }}
</UButton>  
...
</template>

Or
<script setup>
const isLoading = ref(false);
const emit = defineEmits(['method']);
const handleClick = async () => {
    isLoading.value = true;
    try {
        emit('method', form);
    } finally {
        isLoading.value = false;
    }
};
</script>

<template>
...
<UButton :loading="isLoading" @click.prevent="handleClick">
   {{ btn.text }}
</UButton>  
...
</template>

However, this approach had issues with the finally block not executing which makes my button disabled forever

Is the call properly done and issue being the loading state? Why happens if you change that one with your Vue devtools? Also why if you put it below the call in the try? I am not sure how finally works in this case might not get called because of how await works maybe.

emit('method', form) executes each time without any issues. The problem is the isLoading value and how to change it back to false once the method is finished. Using try/catch block or not changes nothing, the end result is always the same.

If I use :
const handleClick = async () => {         isLoading.value = true;         await new Promise(resolve => {             emit('method', form);         });         isLoading.value = false;     };
the isLoading is stuck in true and never goes back to false
If I use this instead:
const handleClick = async () => {         isLoading.value = true;         emit('method', form);         isLoading.value = false;     };
The isLoading is always false and never even changes to true
Yes I can change its value in Vue devtools

Your promise is never fulfilled because you don't call resolve().  Either way, emit is a single code statement that requires a few milliseconds at most to complete, so it switches from false to true so fast you never notice. FYI your component has no knowledge of an event after it's emitted. If there's an async operation happening from the event being captured elsewhere, such as a parent component, your loading state should be handled there instead. Parent can pass loading state down to the child as a prop so all child has to do is bind the prop value to :loading on UButton

because the emit is not async, i suggest you handle the loading value from the parent component (where yo handle the method event) and pass to this component as a prop
